# Numerical Differentiation- Central Difference approximation & Richardson extrapolation

Tags: derivatives, extrapolation

I have been told to derive "the central difference approximation for f''(x) accurate to O(h^4) by applying Richardson extrapolation to the central difference approximation of O(h^2).

I have done this and got:

$$f''(x_i)=\frac{-f(x_{i+2})+16f(x_{i+1})-30f{x_i}+16f(x_{i-1})-f(x_{i-2})}{12h^2}.$$ For error: O(h^4)

using this I have then been given some data points, and computed a f''(0.2) where 0.2 is part of the data set. This is all fine, I am vaguely understanding how this works. However, it is now asking me to estimate the second derivative of $$f(x)=sin(x)+e^{-x}$$
at x=0, using h=0.1 and h=0.5, I literally have no idea how to do this, am i just replacing my $x_{i}, x_{i-1}... $ with 0 and then substituting each value of h? it makes no sense to me. If someone could point me in the right direction that'd be great.

Comment: You let $x_i=0$ and $x_{i+j}=j\cdot h$.

Comment: ok, so I substitute $x_i=j*h$, so I am will get two different results for f''(x_i)... surely that is not correct? also, I don't even have any data points for this function f(x), so where do i get j from?

Comment: You have not understood my comment.  You know what $x_i$, $j$, and $h$ are. That is enough to tell you at which points to evaluate the function.